# Cocos2d+Box2d: How to make crash free vertex generation with VertexHelper?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

Code:

```
b2PolygonShape polyShapeDef;
int num = 19;
b2Vec2 verts[] = {
    b2Vec2(-6.5f / PTM_RATIO, -29.5f / PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(-31.5f / PTM_RATIO, 3.5f / PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(-31.5f / PTM_RATIO, 5.5f / PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(-30.5f / PTM_RATIO, 9.5f / PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(-27.5f / PTM_RATIO, 15.5f / PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(-20.5f / PTM_RATIO, 22.5f / PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(-17.5f / PTM_RATIO, 24.5f / PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(-13.5f / PTM_RATIO, 26.5f / PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(-10.5f / PTM_RATIO, 27.5f / PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(-5.5f / PTM_RATIO, 28.5f / PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(3.5f / PTM_RATIO, 28.5f / PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(8.5f / PTM_RATIO, 27.5f / PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(11.5f / PTM_RATIO, 26.5f / PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(17.5f / PTM_RATIO, 23.5f / PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(25.5f / PTM_RATIO, 15.5f / PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(28.5f / PTM_RATIO, 9.5f / PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(29.5f / PTM_RATIO, 6.5f / PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(29.5f / PTM_RATIO, 2.5f / PTM_RATIO),
    b2Vec2(2.5f / PTM_RATIO, -29.5f / PTM_RATIO)
};

polyShapeDef.Set(verts,num);
polyShapeDef.m_vertexCount = num ;

b2BodyDef polyBodyDef;   
polyBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
polyBodyDef.userData = inSprite;
polyBodyDef.position.Set(inSprite.position.x/PTM_RATIO, inSprite.position.y/PTM_RATIO);
b2Body *parachutBody = world->CreateBody(&polyBodyDef);

b2FixtureDef polyFixtureDef;    // Define the fixture
polyFixtureDef.shape = &polyShapeDef;
polyFixtureDef.density = 20.0f;
polyFixtureDef.friction = 0.9f;

parachutBody->CreateFixture(&polyFixtureDef);
```

// Above vertex list is generated by 'VertexHelper'. Anything wrong with code? getting crash..

Comment: Can you please specify more details?  How does it crash (error messages), do you have a stacktrace?  Have you tried isolating the problem?  If not, do so by making the code as small as possible (will also make it easier for us to help).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a maximum number of vertices Box2D supports for methods like

```
polyShapeDef.Set(verts,num);
```

This number is in `b2_maxPolygonVertices` and I believe by default it limits the number of vertices in a polygon shape to 8 vertices.

While you might increase that number, keep in mind that there's probably a good reason (most likely: performance) why Box2D only allows 8 vertices for polygon shapes. It could very well affect an exponential function whose running time may double for each additional vertex.

The better solution is to reduce the number of vertices, or to attach two or more shapes to the body to make up the body's collision area.

Comment: Thank you Sir. now I reduced vertex count and its working fine.